# counting the number of lines in a text file and compare them to a counter

Tags: c#, file-handling, timepicker

Hi im very new to c# so excuse my code for being all over the place.

In my application i have used the counter to count my if statements, i now want to find a text file called the variable (date) chosen from my timepicker. i now want it to count the amount of lines in that text file and add that number to my count variable and tell me if its less than 13.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           int TotalLines(string date)
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(date))
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (r.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
            return i;
        }
    }

    if
{
    i + counter = <13
}

    MessageBox.Show ("Seats Available");

    else 

    MessageBox.Show ("please chose another date");
    }
 }
```

}

i have just posted that segment of code as all the code in the button is fairly long as i have no doubt gone the long way about it.

thanks for your help

Comment: Please format your code a little bit. BTW: In the current form there are a lot of errors in it.

Comment: Where is the TotalLines() method that you have as well the code needs to be formatted your if statement is incorrect as well use () Parentheses instead of curly braces and after the if() wrap the code block around {} if(i + counte < = 13) {} for example

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean something like this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = TotalLines(date);

    if (counter <= 13)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Seats Available");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please chose another date");
    }
}

public int TotalLines(string date)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(date))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (r.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
        return i;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kyle Uithoven's code appears to be correct. You can simplify further by replacing the `TotalLines` method with:

```
int counter = File.ReadLines(date).Count();
```

Comment: That is beautiful. I did not know you could do that! I need to spend more time using File IO.

Comment: `Count()` is in `System.Linq`

Comment: @McAden: I assume he was referring to `File.ReadLines`, which avoids the need for using a `FileStream` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

C# If-else syntax:

```
if (condition)
{
    //Condition is true
    //Some commands
}
else
{
    //Condition is else
    //Some commands    
 }
```

Better define the TotalLines function outside the button1_click one.

```
public int TotalLines(string date)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(date))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (r.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
        return i;
    }     
}
```